# Symfony4 - How to pass a TokenStorageInterface to an EntityListener?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

I'm currently working on a project created with api-platform and using Symfony4.

My goal is to be able to use a TokenStorage inside of an EntityListener in order to know the identity of my user.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to pass a TokenStorageInterface as an argument.
And the autowiring system doesn't seem to work.

services.yaml :

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.


    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    App\EntityListener\KpiDateListener:
        public: true,
        arguments:
            $tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
```

KpiDateListener.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\EntityListener;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Tests\Fixtures\TestBundle\Manager\UserManager;
use App\Entity\KpiDate;
use App\Entity\StateDate;
use App\Security\User\UserProvider;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException;
use Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class KpiDateListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function postPersist(KpiDate $kpiDate, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        //Here is my function
    }
}
```

I always have the same error :

> Too few arguments to function App\EntityListener\KpiDateListener::__construct(), 0 passed in /srv/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/ContainerAwareEntityListenerResolver.php on line 76 and exactly 1 expected

Is there something wrong or missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message would indicate that autowiring is not enabled for your listener. Autowiring works for services. If your entity listener is not registered as a service, the DI component cannot autowire it, as it does not know about it (and then, instantiating the class will be performed by Doctrine itself).

Try changing to:

```
    App\EntityListener\KpiDateListener:
        autowire: true
        public: true,
        arguments:
            $tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```